# Single jQuery library with Carousel, Accordion, Tabs UI

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion, carousel

Is there any one single jQuery library which can render elements as carousel, accordion and tabs ?

It must have basic features like:

1. Pager and Prev/Next buttons
2. Fade and slide transition effects
3. Horizontal and Vertical orientation
4. Single/Multiple item(s) view

It would be even better if it is responsive and supports swipe gestures.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a Ui framework like Bootstrap [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

1. Accordion -- [Accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-heading)
2. Tabs -- [Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs)
3. Carousel --[carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

Comment: thanks for suggesting Bootstrap, but it does not have all basic features. E.g., in carousel I could not find transition effects.